# How to rewrite this code to use a "for" loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I guess this code can write in for loop, but I have no idea how to do it?
Thanks a lot!

```
worksheet1=pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feature1)
worksheet2=pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feature2)
worksheet3=pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feature3)
worksheet4=pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feature4)
worksheet5=pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feature5)
worksheet6=pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feature6)
```

Comment: have you tried to convert the above code to a for loop?

Comment: Not yet! Beacuse I have no idea how to convert it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
featuresList = [feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4,feature5,feature6]

worksheets = [pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=feat) for feat in featureList]
```

then you can call to `worksheets[1]` wich is worksheet2 and so (one index displacement)

---

**EDIT**

As suggested, A list comprehension is a way to compress an for sentence in one line, it's general form is:

```
 result_list = [do_something for val in iterator]
```

It return a list doing some work over an iterator

Comment: Just a thought for improvement: also mention how the list comprehension used translates to a `for` loop syntax, would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `list` of worksheets and a `list` of features. You shouldn't have the variables worksheet1 through worksheet6 at all, but I don't know how they were initiated so I am reusing them below for lack of alternative. The code you showed could be converted to:

```
worksheets = [] * 6
features = [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6]
for x in zip(worksheets, features):
    x[0] = pd.read_excel(xls,"sheet2",usecols=x[1])
```

Comment: Yap! I got it! It should have a list to collect the variables.
Thanks too

Comment: Oh no! It can't work because I don't have these variables.

Comment: Its true! The `worksheets =` assignment references variables that don't exist or aren't known yet. @Erik take a closer look at the question above, I think it should hopefully make sense.

Comment: @Megan Yes that was my bad, I have edited the answer to fix the problem